# Android Button OnClickListener only fired after clicking other button

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

**I have a `ListFragment` with this row layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="#2eb199" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleField"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Titel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeField"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Plaats"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/card_bg" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="94dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp" >

                        <TextView 
                            android:id="@+id/clientField"
                            android:text="Opdrachtgever"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" /> 

                        <TextView 
                            android:id="@+id/datetimeField"
                            android:text="Datum/Tijd"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" /> 

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/descriptionField"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="14dp" /> 

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="#3e454d" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/detailsButton"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:background="#3e454d"
                        android:text="Meer info"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="#B3B5BD"
                        android:orientation="vertical" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/joinButton"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:background="#3e454d"
                            android:text="Deelnemen"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selector_arrow"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And here I set the listeners in an ArrayAdapter:**

```
detailsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (detailsButtonOnClickListener != null) {
                    detailsButtonOnClickListener.onDetailsButtonClick(position); 
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "DetailsButton OnClickListener triggered but no listener is set.");
                }
            }
        });

        joinButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (joinButtonOnClickListener != null) {
                    joinButtonOnClickListener.onJoinButtonClick(currentInvitation.getId());
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "JoinButton OnClickListener triggered but no listener is set.");
                } 
            }
        });
```

But the `detailsButton` `OnClickListener` on the first row is not fired except if I click another `detailsButton` from a different row first.
I am sure the listeners are set and are working 100% because you can always click the `detailsButton` from another row.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you doing this? `if (detailsButtonOnClickListener != null) {
                    detailsButtonOnClickListener.onDetailsButtonClick(position);`

Comment: Because I want to pass the current row position, and not the current view. So I can open a new DetailsActivity from the data of the current row

Comment: use android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in your xml where you have created the adapter

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

In my ListFragment the method showDetails(int position) is called when the DetailsButtonOnClickListener is fired.

```
@Override
public void onDetailsButtonClick(int position) {
    if (position != currentDetailsPosition) {
        showDetails(position);
    }
}
```

But the variable `currentDetailsPosition` was not initialized and because it was an `int` the default value was `0`. Because the first row `position = 0` the method `showDetails(int position)` was never called because `currentDetailsPosition` was also `0`. But when you click another `detailsButton` the `currentDetailsPosition` was not `0` anymore and therefore the `showDetails(int position)` method was now called.

By changing the `currentDetailsPosition` to an Integer instead of an int and changing the `onDetailsButtonClick(int position)` method to this:

```
@Override
public void onDetailsButtonClick(int position) {
    if (currentDetailsPosition == null || position != currentDetailsPosition) {
        showDetails(position);
    }
}
```

it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, in button's xml layout code, define android:onClick attribute with the method name:

```
android:onClick="sample"
```

then, in java define a click method with the same name as the `android:onClick` value.

```
public void sample (View view)
{ 
  .....
  .....
}
```